# How to verify the origin of a post in php using https

Tags: php, https

How can I ensure that a https post is from a given domain? Consider the following setup: 
A webpage on the frontend server, for example https://www.frontend.com/index.php sends a `https` post redirect to a webpage on a backend server, for example https://www.backend.com/index.php

Now the backend wants to verify that the post is really from  https://www.frontend.com/index.php .

(If the post is not from the frontend server, it should be rejected showing an error message.)
How can this be done in `php`? (as seen from the URLs above I am using SSL)

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but I would pass a token to make sure.

Comment: @Popnoodles But cannot another site (not frontend) just set this variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to the frontend URL, pretending it is the frontend server? See: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/is-server-a-safe-source-of-data-in-php

Comment: Yes which is why I'd pass a token that only those two sites know how to generate.

Comment: Ok I see :) Thanks. I wondered if there were some other mechanisms that could be used, since I am using SSL.

Comment: That said there is probably a proper way to do it using CURL and credentials. I don't know about this though, so hopefully someone will help you out. Possibly SOAP does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common technique here would be to use *request signing*. In short it uses a shared secret (a "password") to hash certain parts of the request to create an authentication token. For example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511138/476).

Specifically for SSL though, you may also use client-side certificates, in which the client sending the request proves his identity. SSL enables mutual authentication, it doesn't have to be one-sided as it typically is.