# Bypassing Login in android application

Tags: android, cookies, authentication

I want to access an online music library from my android application to play its music. The music is accessible on a url lets say www.test.com/music.html.

In order to get to this website though you need to login on www.test.com/index.html

In my Android App I don't want to have to login. So how can I bypass the login screen?

I have thought about a persistent cookie that comes with the app, how can I include this into the android application?

Or is there another solution like putting the login information in the post request?

Comment: Be aware that if you build a mechanism to bypass log-in for Android devices, this could be also used by other clients as well. Also, to answer the question more details on how the log-in system is implemented on the server side are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, cookies is right solution in case you use embedded WebView in your app to log-in. You will need to use [`CookieSyncManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html) for it, look through [this tutorial](http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/05/using-cookiesyncmanager/).

If you perform the log-in by entering username and password to `EditText` and then sending it to server, then you'd better implement [token-based authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592534/what-is-token-based-authentication). However, you may simply save user credentials to `SharedPreferences`, but that's actually a bad practice.

Comment: Then how do you perform the log-in? Just entering username and password to `EditText` and then sending it to server? If so, then... see edited answer :)

Comment: Right now it is just for testing purposes, I want to have the easiest solution possible, like saving the login information in Strings in my Class. But how can I create the cookies and all those kind of stuff

Comment: [`SharedPreferences.Editor.putString(..)`](http://goo.gl/nDzoV) would be the simplest way.

Comment: And why are SharedPrefs a bad practice?

Comment: Because it's a bad idea to store user name and password locally. At least, it should be encrypted then

Answer (score 0):

You could give SharedPreferences a try:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref