# what is the different between Sessions::CookieStore (default) and Sessions::CacheStore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I would like to know in Rails

what is the difference between

```
ActionDispatch::Sessions::CookieStore and ActionDispatch::Sessions::CacheStore
```

For CacheStore, i assume Rails store the session in memory(RAM)?
What about CookieStore, where are they storing?

Kit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CookieStore` is stored in the client's browser as a cookie. The cookie is signed with your application's secret key so theoretically they should not be able to tamper with it. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage) for more information.

`CacheStore` is stored in whatever `ActiveSupport::Cache::Store` is using to store information (i.e. memcached or redis, on the server side not on the client side). See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CacheStore.html) for more information.

Comment: I am thinking if CookieStore, it would be similar to token based  authentication.

Comment: Can you elaborate? A common use case of the session is to store the id of an authenticated user once they enter their username and password. Token based authentication is used to authenticate a user without them giving you their username and password. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592534/what-is-token-based-authentication

Comment: Both of them storing information as cookies, token or sessionID, for each request, they would authenticate using the sessionID / token. That's why i think similiar