# Saving app state in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have done a bit of research on how to do this but can't find any.I have an app that has a `Home` page.On this homepage, there is a `Register` button.I want to implement a system where if the user clicks on this and registers, the app never starts with the `Register` button displayed again,but rather, a `view Profile` button.How do i implement such a system? My guess is to store some boolean value in localstorage, and check this value when the app starts?

**Update:** I just thought i'd add that my jquery mobile app communicates with a Google App Engine (Python) web service which already uses Google's `User's Service`

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [**Local Storage Jquery Mobile**](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/7/13/jQuery-Mobile--adding-Local-Storage).

You have to store data when user click on `Register` button, and every time when app will open it checks is there is any data in `Local Storage`. Then you can use your logic.

You can also use [**HTML5 Local Storage with Jquery Mobile**](http://operationmobile.com/how-to-use-html5-local-storage-with-jquery-mobile/). But some device browser dose not support Local storage if you want to check this you should go for [Modernizer](http://www.modernizr.com/).

This is simple code of checking local storage using modernizer:

```
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    // Supported
}
else {
    // Not Supported
}
```

Comment: So what happens when the device browser doesn't support Local Storage?

Comment: Then you have to save data to server site.

Answer (score 1):

If you only store a boolean after the user is logged-in, yes you know that a user is logged in but you don't know which one.

Te best approach is to store the user's **token** which you will send as a parameter in all requests so that you can validate them.

When entering the website if there is a token you must validate it by querying the server. If it's not valid then you show the register/login page. If the token is valid you could login the user automatically.

Whatever plugin you decide to use be sure to check that if it is a localStorage plugin it also has fallback for cookies. (Maybe some clients will have browsers that don't support localStorage)

On [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) page there are 3 functions that I personally use when I need access to cookies.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1592556/1109883) you have some details about token authentication.

I would advise you to store the token using cookies.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244907/1109883) describes one of the best ways of managing user sessions based on tokens.