# How to use JWT without user and login?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, jwt

I'm making a simple file converter API in Node.js and I'm looking to avoid abuse in requests.
So I'm looking for a way to use JWT without userModel, login etc.

But I can't thing something online.

Thank you

Comment: Without username/password and login, what will be the difference between valid user and guest? Will you send valid user something offline?

Answer (score 5):

we don't need a user or login to create JWT, we can generate a token with any kind of data. Simple just generate a token then pass it to the client after that on file convert request verify the token.

I found similar topic that might help you [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523123/secure-rest-api-without-user-authentification-no-credentials?rq=1)