# What should I return for a login method in my API?

Tags: django, api, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework

There is **Server A**, **Server B** and **Server C**. Also there are account **SUPERUSER** and **customer** accounts.

**Server A** is the API service, it contains all the **customer** credentials.

**Server B** is the oAuth server.

**Server C** is the application which is going to use the API service authenticating any **customer** account but first doing an internal authentication of **SUPERUSER** account via **Server B**.

In short words, I don't know if this method is appropriate, but this is what I think: My API service needs a method called "/authenticate/" only for customers authentication and receiving parameters as user and password. The thing is, what status code should I return in case of success or fail?

Answer (score 0):

For `success` you could return a `status_code 200` and for fail, which is an authentication error, you could return `status_code 403` [Forbidden](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403). In case of success you could also return a [Token authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592534/what-is-token-based-authentication)