# AngularJS how can I hide important DATA

Tags: angularjs, json

I just want to ask what would be the best way to hide sensitive data using anugularJS.

I am developping a VOD (Video On Demand) app in which I have to make movies' links hidden and not accessible by users.

For example, I get this JSON from backend using $http inside a moviesFactory:

```
{ "title": "movieTitle", "link": "www.some-provider-link.com/movie-link.mp4"}
```

And when I need to show the video, I put this JSON in my scope like that:

```
$scope.movie = moviesFactory.getMovie().then(callbackOk, callbackNonOk);
```

My problem is since the scope is accessible from user using chrome extensions or even `angular.element(document.getElementById('anElementId')).scope()`
everyone can access my scope and see the links.

So what am I doing wrong? ANd how can I hide those data?

Comment: Are you returning those links to unauthenticated users? If so why not only return them when the user is authenticated? You could generate a temporary link for your authenticated users that is resolved on the server. Single page apps and authentication do require a different way of thinking than traditional server side rendered apps.

Comment: Offcourse, only authentificated users can watch movies and I want that those authentificated users can NOT see the source

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly by this way, because javascript **is** executed in client side (and you have not full control of the sources you provide to the clients).

And sharing (encrypted/obscured or not) your complete files url ('www.some-provider-link.com/movie-link.mp4') it's NOT a good idea, if you are concerned of the privacy of those files.

You should consider including some sort of authentication (like [tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592534/what-is-token-based-authentication)) and make an API in your server that gives you all the data you needs (like .mp4 files) as a stream of bytes, when a user is authenticated.

Comment: I am already using token authentification. Only authentificated users can watch movies and I want that those authentificated users can NOT see my links and then download directly videos from the provider website. What do you mean stream of bytes?

Comment: I mean that your server may function as a bridge for your provider links: user A wants 'kitty meow.mp4', makes an api request to your server requiring kitty meow.mp4 and your server grab the file from the provider and get back to your client (as a stream of bytes). That's all i can think.