# How to authenticate webapp using token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to create a webtest which will authenticate website using token and load webpage.

Since webtest will run without any manual interaction, I cannot sign in. So I am trying to authenticate using token.

But since website using active directory it uses `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` and `UseCookieAuthentication` for authentication when accessed via browser.

Is there a way to create a webtest like this?

Comment: Can you refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592534/what-is-token-based-authentication

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to create a webtest which will authenticate website using token and load webpage.
>
> But since website using **active directory** it uses **UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication** and **UseCookieAuthentication** for authentication when accessed via browser.

According to your description, I assumed that you may leverage the package [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect) and [Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies) to protect your application with OpenId Connect and Azure AD.

Assuming that your website is hosted by Azure web app, I assume that you could leverage the [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) and configure [Authenticate with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication) instead of using the middle-ware manually in your code. But you could check the current environment in your code and use the middle-ware for authenticating locally.

In order to get the authenticated token from azure web app, you could access the following url via the browser for logging:

```
https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad
```

After logged, you would be redirected to the url as follows:

```
https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done#token={token}
```

You could [URL Decode](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/) the above `token`, retrieve the `authenticationToken` as the authenticated token to access your azure web app as follows:

```
https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/xxx/xxx
Header: x-zumo-auth:{authenticationToken}
```

**Note:** The `authenticationToken` would be expired after an hour.

Moreover, for Azure Active Directory you could also leverage the `id_token` or `access_token` be directly included in the `Authorization` header as a bearer token as follows:

```
https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/xxx/xxx
Header: Authorization:Bearer {id_token or access_token}
```

**Note:** In order to retrieve the `id_token` or `access_token` after logged, you could access the following url via the browser:

```
https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me
```